# OnTap Navigation from gridview.builder method flutter

Tags: flutter, gridview, widget, infinite-loop, gridview.builder

**In this code Navigator.push is executing infinite times**
I am beginner flutter development and developing calculator app and implementing unit converter features in this app.

I created list of units that are displaying using gridview.builder method and display the ConverterCard, and when i added onTap functionality it execute this line of code infinite times that is causing performance issue and new widget is rebuilding again and again :

```
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {       
/// this line is is running infinite times        
return ConverterScreen(appbarName: converterList[widget.index]['name']);     
}));`
```

Please help me to fix that

```
import 'package:calculator_app/contants/convertor_list.dart';
import 'package:calculator_app/screen/convertor_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ConverterCard extends StatefulWidget {
  const ConverterCard(
      {super.key, required this.name, required this.icon, required this.index});
  final int index;
  final String name;
  final IconData icon;

  @override
  State<ConverterCard> createState() => _ConverterCardState();
}

class _ConverterCardState extends State<ConverterCard> {
  void onTapFunc() {
    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
      /// this line is is running infinite times
      return ConverterScreen(appbarName: converterList[widget.index]['name']);
    }));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {},
      child: Card(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Icon(
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                widget.icon,
                size: 30,
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Text(
                widget.name,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is more description of code where is used builder method :
`

```
import 'package:calculator_app/contants/convertor_list.dart';
// import 'package:calculator_app/screen/convertor_screen.dart';
// import 'package:calculator_app/screen/temp_screen.dart';
import 'package:calculator_app/widgets/convertor_card.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ConvertorListScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const ConvertorListScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const List<Map<String, dynamic>> converterGrid = converterList;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Converters List'),
      ),
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
          int crossItemCount = constraints.maxWidth > 600 ? 3 : 2;
          crossItemCount = constraints.maxWidth > 1200 ? 4 : crossItemCount;
          return GridView.builder(
            itemCount: converterGrid.length,
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: crossItemCount,
            ),
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ConverterCard(
                index: index,
                name: converterGrid[index]['name'].toString(),
                icon: converterGrid[index]['icon'],
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}`
```

Comment: Where do you call `onTapFunc`?